# Nested Select ... From a simulated full outer join

Tags: mysql, select, nested-statement

So I have a query; a simulated `FULL OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
LEFT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
UNION
SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
RIGHT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId;
```

However this pulls out a rather large selection, and I only need 2 - 3 fields: `SupplierPartNo` and `MajorEquipmentNo`. I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT SupplierPartNo, MajorEquipmentNo FROM(
  SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
  LEFT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
  RIGHT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
);
```

But that gives me an error `Every derived table must have its own alias: SELECT SupplierPartNo, MajorEquipmentNo FROM( SELECT....`

How can I do a `SELECT` from a previous selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those two particular fields from your dataset, you can directly query like this:

```
SELECT SupplierInfo.SupplierPartNo, MajorEquipment.MajorEquipmentNo 
FROM SupplierInfo
LEFT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
UNION
SELECT SupplierInfo.SupplierPartNo, MajorEquipment.MajorEquipmentNo 
FROM SupplierInfo
RIGHT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
```

If you still want to go with your derived table approach(which I will suggest not to because of the performance) then you can query it like:

```
SELECT a.SupplierPartNo, a.MajorEquipmentNo FROM (
SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
LEFT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
UNION
SELECT * FROM SupplierInfo
RIGHT JOIN MajorEquipment ON SupplierInfo.SupplierId = MajorEquipment.MEId
) a
```